# Linear Maps and Trace

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to show that if a map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n\text{x}n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the properties
 \begin{align}
 1. &\phi(\lambda A)=\lambda \phi(A)\\
 2. &\phi(A+B)=\phi(A)+\phi(B)\\
 3. &\phi(AB)=\phi(BA)
 \end{align}
 for all $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\text{x}n}, \quad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
 then $\exists \quad c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
 $$\phi(A)=c\cdot tr(A)$$

I realize that the trace of a matrix has the three properties listed above, but wouldn't that show that the linear map $\phi$ is the trace itself?
Also, how would I even go about showing this linear map gives a value that scales proportionally to the trace of a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First put $\{E_{ij}\}_{ij}$ the canonical basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. By properties 1 and 2, the tranformation is linear so it is determined by its basis. We only have to prove that: $T(E_{ii})=c$ and $T(E_{ij})=0$ for $i\neq j$. We have that $T(E_{ij})=T(E_{ij}E_{jj})=T(E_{jj}E_{ij})=T(0)=0$, if $i\neq j$. We have that $T(E_{ii})=T(E_{ij}E_{ji})=T(E_{ji}E_{ij})=T(E_{jj})$. Therefore the $c$ we alooking for is $T(E_{11})$.